# 301 redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all my pages from `example.com/video_player/vidinfo/456/game/halo-reach-coop-walkthrough-gameplay-in-hd/vtype/sd/`  to `example.com/video_player/vidinfo/456/game/halo-reach-coop-walkthrough-gameplay-in-hd/`

using 301 redirects in htaaccess, any help is appreciated. Thanks

I want to remove `vtype/sd/` from the url which is of no use anymore because I have added a button in my flash video player for that purpose.

This is what I am currently using in my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^video_player/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /video_player.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
RewriteRule ^video_player/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /video_player.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

Comment: Why did you write `example.com`? http://www.google.com/search?q=video_player%2Fvidinfo%2F456%2Fgame%2Fhalo-reach-coop-walkthrough-gameplay-in-hd%2Fvtype%2Fsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch Permanent (.*)/vtype/sd/ $1/
```